# Test cases are missing on a [test-battery] challenge

Tags: discussion, testing

[This challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10553/build-a-random-number-generator-that-passes-the-diehard-tests) is a [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery), where you need the set of test cases that the challenge provides.

However, the test suite that you are required to use is missing, since the website has gone down. I want to answer the challenge, so what should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just me, but I have some trouble understanding your question. Could you reword it and maybe add a link to the challenge we're discussing?

Comment: @Dennis there you go

Comment: Done. / That's the reason why challenges should be self contained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What should I do with my answer?

The real question is, what should we do with the challenge?

If new answers cannot be scored anymore because some outside resource became unavailable, I see only two possible courses of action.

1. Replace the broken link with a working one.

   In this particular case, the Wayback Machine appears to have mirrored the resource here: https://web.archive.org/web/20161114211602/http://stat.fsu.edu/pub/diehard/
2. Close the challenge, as it no longer has a winning criterion.

Comment: Might want to do more than replace the broken link.  I know that some links are pretty safe from rot, but it might be a good policy to move everything into the question if possible to avoid this problem in the future.

Comment: In general, sure. But there's no good way to move the entire DieHard source code into the challenge body.